# there are 2 equations $2x-3y=13$ and $3x+2y=b$ $1\le b\le100$, $b =$ integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

there are 2 equations $2x-3y=13$ and $3x+2y=b$
$1\le b\le100$, $b$ = integer

$n^2 = x+y$

$x,y$ are the roots from 2 equations above

what value of n is sufficient?

from the 2 equations i get $x+y = 2b/5$

but what is $n$?

Comment: What has your question to do with `ordinary-differential-equations`?

Comment: I get $x=\frac3 {13}b+2$ and $y=\frac2{13}b-3$ so $x+y=\frac5{13}b-1$

Comment: what tags i should pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $b$ we get $x=\frac 3 {13} b+2$ and $y=\frac 2 {13} b-3$. Hence $n^{2}=\frac 5 {13} b-1$. This implies that $\frac 5 {13} b$ is an integer, so $b$ is divisble by $13$. Since $1 \leq b \leq 100$ it follows that $b\in \{13,26,39,52,65,78,91\}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: b is integer means b=1,2,....? but if 5b/13 = integer then, b must be divisible by 13?

Comment: $5b=13k$ for some integer $k$. Since  $(13,5)=1$ this implies that $13$ divides $b$.